# How to hit a endpoint using .p12 certificate using spring-ws-core

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, ssl-certificate, spring-ws

I am using spring-ws-core 2.2.3.RELEASE, one of our client shared ".p12" certificate to hit their service.I know how to hit the webservice using "jks" but i never used ".p12" could anyone already achieved this ?

"WebServiceTemplate" really accept ".p12"?
Do we need to publish the ".p12" into java keystore?
Please someone guide me to achieve this.Your help should be appreciated.